# Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child startupinfo

Tags: python

I am teaching my students to make plots with Python and recently some of them had the following error (they had it on Windows 7 and 8):

File "C:\Users\Tadi\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

I have tried the same script in Python (Spyke, Jupiter Notebook) (using Ubuntu and Windows 7, 32 bits y Windows 10) and I did not have that problem so the script may not be the problem.

Any help will be appreciated, I am not a programmer.

Best

FER

---

```
# Primero importamos las librerias que necesitamos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Aca elegimos el tipo de colormap (gnuplot)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('gnuplot')
# con esta linea permitimos usar un formato de
# texto tipo LATEX
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
# creamos una lista con los valores de D, O, y S
D=([-34.0, -22.5, -30.3, -9.5, -13.6, -15.7, -43.9, -42.9, -26.3, 10.8, 10.9, 21.0, -14.2, -41.6, -17.5, -29.3, 3.0, 7.6])
O=([-3.15, -0.86, -2.47, 1.72, 0.43, -0.12, -5.64, -5.35, -1.18, 7.11, 7.02, 8.61, 0.56, -4.64, 0.53, -1.18, 4.28, 8.21])
S=([15.8, 17.72, 12.25, 32.5, 47.05, 50.4, 37.5, 36.3, 236, 338, 315, 353, 92.7, 29.17, 132.5, 56.98, 42.7, 379.8])

# Esto para plotear la grilla de puntos (dotted)
plt.grid(linestyle='dotted')

# generamos el grafico
sc = plt.scatter(O, D, c=S, vmin=0, vmax=380, s=35, cmap=cm)

# agregamos detalles y guardamos
plt.xlabel(r'$\delta ^{18}O_{water}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\delta ^2H_{water}$')
plt.colorbar(sc, label=r'$Salinity$ [ppt]')

#plt.savefig('iso_S.pdf', dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Based on initial testing, it appears to be a problem with plt not finding the dependencies for `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having the same issue, and I can't find a fix either. Hoping someone more knowledgeable will have a solution, but trying deleting the tex.cache file as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373388/how-to-get-matplotlib-and-latex-work-together) didn't work. If you leave out that text formatting line, it works, though, so that may be a temporary solution for your students. They may have to restart their python environments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I really appreciate it, best regards, FER