# LaTex in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, sympy

I am trying to connect LaTex in matplotlib and I can’t do it right.

I did based on [this](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) information. Installed MiKTeX, dvipng and Ghostscript.

```py
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('agg') 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sympy import latex
    ...

    # sympy.latex() returned \left[\begin{matrix}2 & 4 & 6\\4 & 6 & 8\\8 & 6 & 4\end{matrix}\right]
    latex_to_img(r"$\left[\begin{matrix}2 & 4 & 6\\4 & 6 & 8\\8 & 6 & 4\end{matrix}\right]$", FILE_NAME_MATRIX)

    ...
    def latex_to_img(str_latex, file_name):

        plt.rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
        plt.rc('text', usetex=True)

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
        ax.set_axis_off()
        t = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, str_latex, 
                horizontalalignment='center', 
                verticalalignment='center',
                fontsize=32, 
                color='black')
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        bbox = t.get_window_extent()
        fig.set_size_inches(bbox.width/80, bbox.height/80) # dpi=80
        save(file_name, config.FILE_EXPANSION)
```

I get such a list:

> RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
>   b'$\\left[\\begin{matrix}2 & 4 & 6\\\\4 & 6 & 8\\\\8 & 6 & 4\\end{matrix}\\right]$'
>
> Here is the full report generated by latex:
>   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex)
>   restricted \write18 enabled.
>   entering extended mode
>   (c:/Users/myname/.matplotlib/tex.cache/7b0c91ed78ceb07701f3d2b71c0c8048.te x
>   LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>   Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
>
> Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.`
>   width' (5058.9pt) is ignored.
>
> Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.`
>   height' (5058.9pt) is ignored.
>
> ) (./7b0c91ed78ceb07701f3d2b71c0c8048.au x)
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
>   *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
>   *geometry* detected driver: dvips
>   (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd)
>   ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
>   l.14 ...000000}{\sffamily $\left[\begin{matrix}2 &
>   4 & 6\4 & 6 & 8\8 & 6 &...
>   No pages of output.
>   Transcript written on 7b0c91ed78ceb07701f3d2b71c0c8048.lo g.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get matplotlib and latex work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373388/how-to-get-matplotlib-and-latex-work-together)

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex']=True
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.unicode']=True
```

Comment: It was added

```python
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
```

about 

```python
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.unicode']=True
```

> The text.latex.unicode rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 2.2 and will be removed > in 3.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the ampersand (&).
Found a solution [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Misplaced%20alignment%20tab%20character%20&)